# A form produce GET method instead a POST method

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I am testing the jquerymobile and I am trying to make a login page with a POST method, but everytime I press the submit button I get a GET response, can someone help me?

This is my code:

```
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">

  <!-- Extra Codiqa features -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="codiqa.ext.css">

  <!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->
  <script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Extra Codiqa features -->
  <script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/codiqa.ext.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- Home -->
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-icon="alert">
        <h3>
            HEADER
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form action="login.php" method="POST" name="formulario">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="textinput2">
                    Usuario
                </label>
                <input name="" id="username" name="username" placeholder="" value="" type="text" data-mini="true">
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="textinput3">
                    Clave
                </label>
                <input name="" id="password" name="password" placeholder="" value="" type="password" data-mini="true">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" data-theme="b" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right" value="Validar" data-mini="true">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>
            FOOTER
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After submit the page you can find a ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
  string(3) "GET" message.

Regards.

Comment: What happens in login.php? Are you sure it doesn't redirect you?

Comment: Is the form shown submitted by the submit button shown, or do you have some JavaScript doing an Ajax call or something?

Comment: This is the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Solve my problem with the following line:

```
<form action="" method="POST" data-ajax="false">
```

:-)

Comment: did it just post to the current url?

Comment: Yes, just reload the same page with the post content.